# Woocomerce как добавить текст

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Есть магазин на wordpress, есть задача добавить в каждый товар одинаковое информационное сообщение (доставка бесплатно, гарантия 2 месяца и т.д), подскажите пожалуйста плагин, который может решить данную задачу. Или может есть другие способы это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем случае зайди в папке активной темы woocommerce/content-sigle-product.php, это шаблон который отвечает за отображение страници товара, можно добавить статичный текст прямо в этот файл, если править нужно какую-либо конкретную область страници товара, то можно воспользоваться одним из фильтров или экшенов, который содержит этот шаблон.